# Does sfdx support CSV import to sandboxes?

Tags: salesforcedx

Haven't bothered to just try it myself yet, but hopefully its not yet another obvious oversight by the sfdx team :)

A lot of sfdx stuff targets scratch orgs, although they brought deploys to sandboxes recently. Conceptually csv imports are prolly using same ol' API.

Should work aye?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `force:data:bulk` commands, which use CSV data and talk to the Bulk API, are not scratch-org specific. They work fine, for example, with developer orgs - I just tried it - and sandboxes would be the same once they're authorized with SFDX.

```
$ cat > test.csv
Name
Test Account 1
Test Account 2

$ sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -i Id -f test.csv -s Account -u my@username.org

Check batch #1’s status with the command:
sfdx force:data:bulk:status -i 7501R00000VnfXXXXX -b 7511R00000fKeXXXXX
```

Two accounts are successfully imported.